# Inside /outside test of the point on 2D plane

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

Suppose I have one plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0.$ I want to test $(x, y, z)$ is inside of this plane or outside.

**My attempt:1** Then draw normal N on that plane which point away from the observer [Image1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0nVH.jpg)

If $Ax+By+Cz+D>0$
or $(-A)x+(-B)y+(-C)z+(-D)<0$ then $(x, y, z)$ is outside of the plane.

And if $Ax+By+Cz+D<0$
or $(-A)x+(-B)y+(-C)z+(-D)>0$ then $(x, y, z)$ is inside of the plane.

**My attempt:2** Now draw the normal N on that plane which point towards the observer [image2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfZ7I.jpg)

If $Ax+By+Cz+D<0$
or $(-A)x+(-B)y+(-C)z+(-D)>0$ then $(x, y, z)$ is outside of the plane.

And if $Ax+By+Cz+D>0$
or $(-A)x+(-B)y+(-C)z+(-D)<0$ then $(x, y, z)$ is inside of the plane.

My question is my both attempts are right? Can anybody help me to understand.

Comment: You haven't any "canonical" inside vs. outside halfspace (remember this name). You can only take your own definition ; for example inside = the halfspace where the origin is situated.

Comment: @Jean if I  choose my own definition as I mentioned inside/outside test , it will be correct?

Comment: You should provide a definition of inside and outside.

Comment: @Ozoomer it's true for front and behind test?

Comment: @Ozoomer could you please answer this question and remove my confusion?

Comment: @Jean please answer this question.

Comment: Yes replacing in the equation $=0$ either by $<0$ or $>0$ gives the condition that $(x,y,z)$ belong to one or the other **"halfspaces"**.

Comment: @Jean just confirm that >0 or <0 both imply inside or outside based on implementation?

Comment: @Jean I am waiting for your answer. My understanding depends on you. Please save me.

Comment: The problem is that you don't use a correct terminology. Everybody will stumble on "inside of the plane" which is not what you want to say because it means in english "belongs to the plane". Use also  "halfspace". The single criteria I advise you to use is whether "is a point (x,y,z) in the same halfspace as the origin (where the observer is supposed to be)" $\iff \ d \ $ and $ \ ax+by+cz+d$ have the same sign.

Comment: @jean instead inside/ outside if I use behind/front, it will be okay?

Comment: Yes for these terms. The correct approach is "two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ (one of them being for example the position of the observer) and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are in the same half space iff $ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d$ and $ax_2+by_2+cz_2+d$ have the same sign." That's all.

Comment: "@jean is a point (x,y,z) in the same halfspace as the origin (where the observer is supposed to be)" ⟺ d  and  ax+by+cz+d have the same sign. "-- it maybe consider as inside or outside based on implementation?

Comment: If I say Ax+By+Cz+D>0 then (x, y, z) is the outside of the plane and if I say Ax+By+Cz+D<0 then (x, y, z) is the inside of the plane, both are right based on implementation?

Comment: It would be correct, indeed.

Comment: @Jean Could you insert your summary in answer, I will accept it. Please, I am imploring you.

Comment: OK, I am going to do it.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/48636/7678, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4325904/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a plane with equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ defining two halfspaces, a good guideline is as follows:

"Two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$  and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are in the same halfspace if and only if $(ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d)$ and $(ax_2+by_2+cz_2+d)$ have the same sign."

If one of them is the position of the observer, and that this position is the origin $(0,0,0)$, this test becomes :

Point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is on the same side of the plane as the observer iff $ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d$ and $d$ have the same sign.

You can call this halfspace the "halfspace of the observer" ("front halfspace" is kind of ambiguous).

Example: Consider the plane with equation $x+y+z-1=0$ (intersecting the axes in $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$), a point like $(x,y,z)=(-2,-3,-4)$ is on the same halfplane as the origin because $-2-3-4-1=-10$ has the same sign as $d=-1$.

Edit 1: If your plane is defined by three points $P,Q,R$ in this order, it defines a natural orientation of the plane, then a **natural normal** by taking the cross product $\vec{N}=\vec{PQ} \times \vec{QR}$.

Edit 2: If the coefficient $c$ of variable $z$ is non zero, you can extract:

$$z=a'x+b'y+c'$$

In this case, you consider it as a surface, and you have **un-ambiguous** above and below halfspaces.

Comment: Ax+By+Cz+D=0 and −Ax−By−Cz−D=0 are opposite sides of the plane?

Comment: No, you cannot say that: it is the **same** equation (one does not modify an equation by multiplying it by a constant, here $-1$).

Comment: I have one confusion. When normal vector pointing away from observer then if Ax+By+Cz+D>0 always and when normal pointing towards the observer then Ax+By+Cz+D<0 always?

Comment: The problem is that, due to the fact (as we have said) that $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ and $$−Ax−By−Cz−D=0$ indistinguishable, you see that we cannot decide "which is which" between $(A,B,C)$ and $(-A,-B,-C)$. I have had an idea : see the Edit I have mde in my answer.

Comment: See a second little Edit.

Answer (score 1):

The sign of D tells you on what "side" the origin is:

- When $D = 0$, $Ax+By+Cz+D = 0$ contains the origin. Notice that $(0, 0, 0)$ satisfy the equation $Ax+By+Cz+D = 0$.
- When $D > 0$, $Ax+By+Cz+D > 0$ contains the origin. Notice that replacing $(0, 0, 0)$ in the equation $Ax+By+Cz+D = 0$ leaves you with $D = 0$, and $D$ is positive. Meaning that the origin satisfies $Ax+By+Cz+D > 0$ when $D$ is positive.
- When $D < 0$, $Ax+By+Cz+D < 0$ contains the origin. By the same logic as above, replacing $(0, 0, 0)$ in the equation $Ax+By+Cz+D = 0$ leaves you with $D = 0$, but in this case $D$ is negative. Meaning that the origin satisfies $Ax+By+Cz+D < 0$ when $D$ is negative.

And, of course, points that give you the same sign are on the same side. See also: [How to determine if a point lies on the same side of the plane that origin does?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607163/how-to-determine-if-a-point-lies-on-the-same-side-of-the-plane-that-origin-does)

---

And I remind you that you could flip all the sings on a plane equation (that is, go form $Ax+By+Cz+D = 0$ to $-Ax-By-Cz-D = 0$) and it defines the same plane. However, you flipped the "sides".

---

From there, it is convention. What convention?

For a clear example, if we are working in camera space and we want to know if something is "behind" a plane. Where "behind" means on the other side from the camera. Remember that the camera in camera space is at the origin. So "behind" is the side that does not contain the origin.

Be aware that different conventions might apply to different contexts. If in doubt, pick one and stick to it.

Comment: Ax+By+Cz+D=0 representing one side and −Ax−By−Cz−D=0 are opposite sides of the plane?

Comment: @Ponting No. It is the same equation. It is the same plane. However, the inequations you would be making for the sides would be flipped. To be more precise Ax+By+Cz+D > 0 is the same as -Ax-By-Cz-D < 0, notice the comparison went from greater than to lesser than.

Comment: @Ponting See here https://www.geogebra.org/m/jgp9pppg - as you can see, the values of A, B and C define the normal. While D slides the plane along the normal. So, you can change the direction of the normal (change the sign of A, B and C) and change the sign of D to arrive to the same plane. But now the side that the normal is pointing is the opposite.

Comment: "the inequations you would be making for the sides would be flipped. "--how?

Comment: @Ponting You start with these sides: Ax+By+Cz+D > 0 and Ax+By+Cz+D < 0. And then you redefine A to be the negative of the value it had, and similarly we do with B, C and D.  We still have two sides: Ax+By+Cz+D > 0 and Ax+By+Cz+D < 0. But Ax+By+Cz+D < 0 now refers to what was Ax+By+Cz+D > 0, and Ax+By+Cz+D > 0 now refers to what was Ax+By+Cz+D < 0. So, we flipped the sides. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: understood. .I have one confusion. When normal vector pointing away from observer then if Ax+By+Cz+D>0 always and when normal pointing towards the observer then Ax+By+Cz+D<0 always?

Comment: @Ponting The normal points to Ax+By+Cz+D>0. So, when the normal vector is pointing away from the observer, it means that the observer is at Ax+By+Cz+D<0. And when the normal vector is pointing towards the observer, it means that the observer is at Ax+By+Cz+D>0. I don't know if that answers your question.